# Cloud SQL disk size is much larger than actual database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Cloud SQL reports that I've used ~4TB of SSD storage, but my database is only ~225 GB. What explains this discrepancy? Is there something I can delete to free up space? If I moved it to a different instance, would the required storage go down?

Comment: this could be affected by many thing. what is the database engine you're using (postgres, mysql, or other thing)? from there, we need to check is there a lot of dead tuple that has not been cleaned?

Comment: It's postgres, and I have run VACUUM FULL on all tables and it didn't change the amount of storage as reported through GCP's SQL overview.

Comment: hmmm... I assume this could be because of the size of a toast table. can you do a `vacuum full verbose analyze table_name` and put the output in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options about why your Cloud SQL storage has increase:

-Did you enable [Point-in-time recovery](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/pitr#disk-usage)? PITR uses write-ahead logs and if you enabled this feature, that could be the reason why of your increases.

-Have you used temporary tables and you have not deleted them?

If none of the above applies to you, I highly recommend you to open a [case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) with GCP support team so that they take a look at your Cloud SQL instance.

On the other hand, you should open a case to decrease the disk size to a smaller one so it won’t be necessary to create a new instance and copy all the data to that new instance in addition that shrinking the disk is done at Google's end making the effort from you the lowest possible.

A maintenance window can be scheduled where Google can proceed with this task and you may want to schedule a maintenance window to minimize the impact of the downtime. For this case it is necessary to know the new disk size and when you would like to perform this operation.

Finally, if you prefer to use the migration method, you should [export](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting) the DB, then create the new instance, [import](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing) the DB and synchronize the old one with the new one to have all the data in both instances to which can take several hours to complete those four steps.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify what kind of database. In my case, for a MySQL database, there were several hundred GB as binary logs (mysql flag).
You could check with:

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```